# For loop index out of range ArgumentOutOfRangeException when multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, lambda, for-loop

I'm getting some strange behavior... when I iterate over the `dummyText` `List` in the `ThreadTest` method I get an index out of range exception (`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`), but if I remove the threads and I just print out the text, then everything works fine.

This is my main method:

```
public static Object sync = new Object();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ThreadTest();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This method throws the exception:

```
private static void ThreadTest()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running ThreadTest");
    Console.WriteLine("Running ThreadTest");
    List<String> dummyText = new List<string>()
    { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", 
      "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"};

    for (int i = 0; i < dummyText.Count; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => PrintThreadName(dummyText[i])); // <-- Index out of range?!?
        t.Name = ("Thread " + (i));
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }
}

private static void PrintThreadName(String text)
{
    Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    while (true)
    {
        lock (sync)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " running " + text);
            Thread.Sleep(1000+rand.Next(0,2000));
        }
    }
}
```

This does not throw the exception:

```
private static void ThreadTest()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running ThreadTest");
    List<String> dummyText = new List<string>()
    { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", 
      "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"};

    for (int i = 0; i < dummyText.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dummyText[i]); // <-- No exception here
    }
}
```

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you pass a local variable into a thread or `ThreadPool` delegate through a closure, you need to make a copy of the variable.  As in:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dummyText.Count; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    Thread t = new Thread(() => PrintThreadName(dummyText[index]));
    // ...
}
```

If you don't do this, then the variable basically gets passed in by reference, and the index will exceed the bounds of the array at the very end of the `for` loop (which may happen long before the closure is ever executed).

Comment: Shouldn't the copy be made outside of the lambda expression, since the lambda expression isn't invoked until the thread actually starts?

Comment: @Michael: Wow, I must be getting tired, I would never write that!  Thanks for the quick catch.

Comment: You just saved me SO much time and headache. I've been fighting with this for days narrowing down this bug. +1