# IndexOutOfRangeException is thrown when starting a new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, indexoutofboundsexception

When I run the following code piece, a IndexOutOfRangeException is thrown. It appears that i is 2 when the exception is thrown. My understanding is that the new thread is started after the value of i has been changed. Is there a way to make this code safe from this kind of problem?

```
int x[2] = {1, 3};
int numberOfThreads = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        DoWork(x[i]);
    }).Start();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [For loop index out of range ArgumentOutOfRangeException when multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741870/for-loop-index-out-of-range-argumentoutofrangeexception-when-multithreading)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the *variable* `i` is being captured, and by the time the thread actually gets to start, it's 2.

Use this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
    int value = x[i];
    new Thread(() => DoWork(value)).Start();
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (int value in x)
{
    int copy = value;
    new Thread(() => DoWork(copy)).Start();
}
```

Or:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
    int copyOfI = i;
    new Thread(() => DoWork(x[copyOfI])).Start();
}
```

In each case, the lambda expression will capture a new variable on each iteration of the loop - a variable which *won't* be changed by subsequent iterations.

In general, you should avoid capturing the loop variable in a lambda expression which will be executed later. See [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) on the topic for more details.

As of C# 5, it's likely that the `foreach` loop behaviour will be changed to avoid this being a problem - but the `for` loop equivalent would still be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are closing over the loop variable, to get the *current value* of `i` use a local copy instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
    int localI = i;
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        DoWork(x[localI]);
    }).Start();
}
```