# Issues With Manual Event Handlers WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am programmatically creating menu items and adding event handlers to them, and for some reason I can't seem to get each menu item's event to register its own unique information. For example:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Slideshow.Speeds.GetLength(0); i++) 
            {

                MenuItem m = new MenuItem() { Header = this.Slideshow.Speeds[i, 0] };

                //Set initial checked MenuItem
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    m.IsChecked = true;
                }


                m.Click += (s, e) => {

                    foreach (MenuItem m_ in this.slideshowSpeedMenuItem.Items)
                    {
                        m_.IsChecked = false;
                    }

                    m.IsChecked = true;

                    this.Slideshow.CurrentSpeed = (int)this.Slideshow.Speeds[i, 1];

                    //i is always the same. i SHOULD be getting a different entry in the array
                    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());

                };

                this.slideshowSpeedMenuItem.Items.Add(m);

            }
```

Why is i always the same for each menu item's click event? The idea is to have each menu item do some stuff with a different given speed, as indicated by i.

Comment: You're capturing `i` in the lambda expression, and then incrementing it. You need a *copy* of `i`. I'll find a good question that this is a duplicate of...

Comment: Humbug - the dupe I logged is for `foreach` instead of `for`. Finding a better one now...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867906/ is probably closer.