# Task.WaitAll gets stuck

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
    var taskList = new Task<string>[masterResult.D.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < masterResult.D.Count; i++)        //Go through all the lists we need to pull (based on master list) and create a task-list
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            Task<string> getDownloadsTask = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(agilityApiUrl + masterResult.D[i].ReferenceIdOfCollection + "?$format=json"));
            taskList[i] = getDownloadsTask;
        }
    }

    Task.WaitAll(taskList.Cast<Task>().ToArray());      //Wait for all results to come back
```

The code freezes after Task.WaitAll... I have an idea why, it's because client is already disposed at the time of calling, is it possible to delay its disposal until later? Can you recommend another approach?

Comment: Well, *test* the hypothesis: what happens when the `using` is moved around everything else? Does this confirm or reject the "idea"?

Comment: Is it running in an async function?  Is it async all the way "up"?

Comment: What is the outer code? It's important it's async all the way down the call stack.

Comment: No, the function is synchronous

Comment: The outer method is presumably irrelevant (and definitely not async) since `Task.WaitAll` is called.

Comment: You should push the `using` of the `client` to the outermost scope (around the whole thing, including the `WaitAll`

Comment: this was actually my initial approach, but sadly WebClient can only handle one request per instance

Comment: Since `taskList` is already a `Task<string>[]` and arrays are co-variant, you don't need the `.Cast<Task>().ToArray()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create and dispose the WebClient within your task.  I don't have a way to test this, but see if points you in the right direction:

```
    var taskList = new Task<string>[masterResult.D.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < masterResult.D.Count; i++)        //Go through all the lists we need to pull (based on master list) and create a task-list
    {
        taskList[i] = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                return client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(agilityApiUrl + masterResult.D[i].ReferenceIdOfCollection + "?$format=json"));

            }
        });
    }

    Task.WaitAll(taskList.Cast<Task>().ToArray());
```

Comment: I got this method to work, except you will need to reassign the loop index to a new variable otherwise you will get an OutOfRange exception. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741870/for-loop-index-out-of-range-argumentoutofrangeexception-when-multithreading

Comment: Yeah, when I did something like this I just used a `List<Task>` and then used `.ToArray()`.  Not surprising something would go a little wonky with the loop index.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how that code would ever work, since you dispose the `WebClient` before the task was run.

You want to do something like this:

```
var taskList = new Task<string>[masterResult.D.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < masterResult.D.Count; i++)        //Go through all the lists we need to pull (based on master list) and create a task-list
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    Task<string> task = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(agilityApiUrl + masterResult.D[i].ReferenceIdOfCollection + "?$format=json"));
    task.ContinueWith(x => client.Dispose());
    taskList[i] = task;
}

Task.WaitAll(taskList.Cast<Task>().ToArray());      //Wait for all results to come back
```

i.e. if you dispose the `WebClient` in the first loop, it's not allocated when you trigger the tasks by using `Task.WaitAll`. The `ContinueWith` call will be invoked once the task completes and can therefore be used to dispose each `WebClient` instance.

However, to get the code to execute concurrent requests to a single host you need to configure the service point. Read this question: [Trying to run multiple HTTP requests in parallel, but being limited by Windows (registry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960056/trying-to-run-multiple-http-requests-in-parallel-but-being-limited-by-windows)

Comment: It doesn't, quite run, that is correct, it freezes when it tries.

Comment: Wasnt me, but I am going to try your solution and +1 if works

Comment: -1 for a comment posing as an answer, but even now, this is not the problem, and that's not good code in your suggestion. WebClient can and should be reused for multiple requests.

Comment: @weston, webclient does not support concurrent requests, I already thought of this approach

Comment: Maybe you can dispose clients on Task.ContinueWith instead of holding a separate list, right?

Comment: @weston: My answer is about async vs dispose in general. Haven't looked into WebClient

Comment: WebClient dispose does nothing, like a MemoryStream dispose. So this is not the issue. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/9726/12729

Comment: In that case, taking WebClient out of using should fix it.

Comment: Except the WebClient is getting disposed before it can possibly have a chance to complete.  So yeah, it probably is the issue.

Comment: weston: Not true, check reference source; http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs

Comment: Weston: The dispose is the issue and you can invoke multiple webclients just like in the code.

Comment: weston: So again, what is the -1 for?

Comment: A non useful answer.

Comment: 1. WebClients can start multiple tasks

Comment: 2. Tasks WebClients start do not share a life span with the WebClient that started them

Comment: WebClients do not support concurrent requests, which is the point of using asynchronous calls here. Therefore you cannot reuse instances of Webclient

Comment: 3. The dispose method you pointed me to is probably related to the many synchronous methods on WebClient.

Comment: @weston Please atleast try before -1 for god sake! This is the error for multiple requests (System.NotSupportedException): WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz When I downvoted it was just a comment. OP will try, then we will see. In meantime don't downvote my answer just because you don't agree with my comments on here.

Comment: @weston I did test it and it does not support that, I didn't downvote for your comments, your answer is not relevent to the question. I'm gonna upvote Dave's answer since it is a cleaner approach.

Comment: It would appear I am wrong on concurrent requests and reuse of webclient. However it gives a very clear exception, not the deadlock they are apparently experiencing.